# действие versus деятельность

Tags: словоупотребление

From what I understand, both can mean **activity**, but действие also means **action**.

However, they seem similar enough that I don't know when to use which.

According to this [frequency list](http://dict.ruslang.ru/freq.php?act=show&dic=freq_s), действие is ranked #83 among Russian nouns, #302 overall. деятельность is ranked #94 among Russian nouns, #322 overall. Given the prevalence of these 2 words, I believe a deeper understanding of when to use each is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Деятельность* is mostly about *working activities*, while *действие* is about *actions* and *functioning activities*.

But note that the notion of working activity is rather vague. For example, *higher nervous activity* = *высшая нервная деятельность*, that is brain really *works*, not just *functioning* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Действие means that the process will be short.
Деятельность is the long-running process.

For example:

- brushing teeth is a short process. It's an action as действие.
- working activity is a long process so it means рабочая деятельность

Comment: Also, it will a good example that action (действие) has begin and end, however activity (деятельность) sometimes doesn't have the end.

Answer (score 0):

Действие is a single act while деятельность is a number of different actions with (or without) common purpose.

So, деятельность can consist of many действие.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **действие** is action, while **деятельность** is activity. And I can't remember any exceptions.